# What were the votes for Hawkgirl to remain in the Justice League?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

This question concerns the *Justice League* and the *Justice League Unlimited* television series within the DC Animated Universe.

In *Justice League* episodes 50-52 (Starcrossed), it is revealed that Hawkgirl was working undercover for the Thanagarian military.  Her information about Earth and the Justice League's weaknesses allowed the "Hawkmen" to capture the Justice League and, unbeknownst to her, build a hyperspace bypass generator that would destroy Earth.

At the end of the episodes, the Justice League (with Hawkgirl's help) destroy the hyperspace bypass generator and save the Earth.  Because of her treachery, the other members of the Justice League hold a meeting to vote on Hawkgirl's continued membership within the Justice League. The result of the vote is never disclosed due to Hawkgirl's voluntarily resignation from the league. However, it is obvious that the Flash voted for her to stay; it is also obvious through this episode (and several others in *Justice League Unlimited*) that Wonder Woman wanted to expel her from the League.

In *Justice League Unlimited* episode 11 (Wake the Dead), it was revealed that the original League voted for her to remain in the Justice League. It was also revealed that Green Lantern abstained from voting and Superman "broke the tie." This means that only 5 individuals voted with the end result being 3-2.  Superman's, the Flash's, and Wonder Woman's votes give a preliminary result of 2-1. That leaves Batman and Martian Manhunter to fill the two remaining (opposing) votes.

**Is there any indication (in other episodes or otherwise) on how these two voted?**

Comment: Earth was going to be destroyed to make way for a hyperspace bypass? Alert the estate of Douglas Adams, I smell a lawsuit!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The vote was 3-2 in favor of her staying. From context clues in the episodes "Wake the Dead" and "Star Crossed" we know that Flash was for her. Wonder Woman was against her. GL abstained, and that Superman broke the tie. It's left to speculate which way Batman and Manhunter voted. Here comes the point where we have to do a bit of detective work.

It is my conclusion that Manhunter was for her and that Batman voted to kick her out. Here is why I feel this way: Manhunter seemed to sympathize with her prior to the vote so we can assume that he was for her.

But, that would mean Batman was against her. Which doesn't really make sense since we know Batman DOES believe in redemption and forgiveness. He knows that she sided with them in the end when it mattered. So why did vote against her then? Simple.

The vote wasn't about her anymore, but rather about Superman.

Let me explain. Batman is smart enough to figure out which way the other members are likely to vote. (If we can do it surely Batman can) He also recognized that Superman was on the fence still. So what happened? Batman called for the vote and voted against her. Not because he didn't trust her anymore. But rather to force a tie. 2 votes for her to stay and 2 votes to kick her out.

Batman forced a tie in order to MAKE Superman make the final decision and to truly act as the leader of the team. Batman was testing Superman to see what he would do. To see if he could forgive her and believe in redemption or if he would kick her out and live with his decision.

Batman is the ultimate detective and tactician, he is always on the watch to see if Superman is ever going to start slipping and become a threat to the Earth. Batman for the Win!!!

Answer (score 6):

#### In the animated show at least, it's never explained.

I've watched Justice League / Justice League Unlimited straight through enough times to confidently say they never explain which way Batman and J'onn vote in regards to Hawkgirl.

Best *guess* would be The Martian Manhunter voted to keep her and Batman voted to kick her out, bringing the vote to 3-2.

Can't really stress *guess* enough here btw, who knows the inner workings of the minds of Batman and a martian?

Answer (score 3):

Like Daft's answer said, it's never mentioned in the shows.

In a somewhat separate (but still DCAU) source, Batman doesn't seem to have a problem with similar (possible) treachery in Justice League: Doom, when he defends his actions that nearly got every single Justice League member killed by

> having a personal dossier on each member and their weaknesses in case they became "compromised", all of which were stolen by mirror man after a diversion

so there is a good chance that he would have voted for her to stay, other feelings and considerations notwithstanding.

Then again, she did join with the intention of malice from the beginning, so that might be a strike against her in his eyes.

Comment: @Daft I would not be surprised if Batman wanted to keep her close(r); he probably doesn't consider her much of a threat (she can fly and is about as strong as Batman with an electrified mace), but as an envoy/hostage/link between Earth and an entire world of warrior hawk-people who are interested in fighting/destroying his planet, she is infinitely more valuable.

Comment: Batman is only a part time leaguer, he doesn't really care about the league as much as the civilian population affected. That said, batman does believe in absolution when merited. Harley ' s day off, he doesn't pounce. Same with Riddler and Penguin in their legal and even slightly illegal endeavors. He probably forgives but doesn't forget. And would rather keep her close and watched instead of running loose.

Answer (score -1):

Martian Manhunter voted to keep her in. He argued for her along Flash prior to the vote, and Batman is, not without good reason, distrusting of aliens and outsiders in general throughout the series.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Can you cite the source you gleaned this information from?  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

How did the Justice League vote? Simple:

**FOR**:
Flash,
Martian Manhunter,
Batman

**AGAINST**:
Wonder Woman,
Superman

**ABSTAINED**:
Green Lantern

"But, didn't they say that Superman voted for Shayera, breaking a tie?", you may be asking.
Yes, they did. In *Justice League Unlimited*.

"So? What does that have to do with anything?", you may once again be questioning.

Let's look at some facts: Superman said, "I feel for her. But after everything that's happened, I honestly don't know if I could ever completely trust her again." - (direct quote).

Batman doesn't trust anyone anyway. Knowing how she fought with the League in the end, Hawk Girl's betrayal would make no difference to him.

Why, then, did they say Superman's vote was in favor of Shayera? Because, Superman is a boy scout. And they have to make him look good no matter what. Therefore, when they were revealing who voted what, they changed it to make it look like Superman voted for Shayera.

He said in *Justice League Unlimited*, "I believe in second chances. I believe in redemption. But mostly, I believe in my friends." - (direct quote). But he said he didn't even know if he could trust her again in *Justice League*. The writers changed the facts.

Batman voted in favor of Shayera. Not Superman.

Comment: How does this square with Superman voting to break a tie?  If he's on the losing side of the vote he couldn't have broken a tie.

Answer (score -2):

I know it’s way late, but this was the vote:

- wonder woman - out
- batman - out
- GL - abstain
- J'onn - in
- flash - in
- superman - in (deciding vote)

This is from watching both JL and JLU (very recently), and how the
arguments went for each side, and the following episodes.

At the end of s1 e11 of JLU, GL says supes was the deciding vote with 3-2 to keep Shayera in the league.

It is pretty easy to figure out the votes after that. WW was clearly for kicking her out, MM was for keeping her in, Flash (at least his libido) voted for in, and if GL abstained and supes was the deciding factor, it’s easy to guess bats voted out.

> When you have eliminated all which is impossible, then whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this, or is it just your own headcanon?

Comment: I’m not clear how you’ve determined that it was impossible for Martian Manhunter to have voted to expel her.

Comment: What is the source of that quote, and how is it relevant to the question/answer?

Comment: @velorum - as i said, it is in the episodes. so since i have to go back in
s2e26: Starcrossed part 3, time index starting at 19:30 
WW - "she exploited our weaknesses, betrayed us."
TF -  "come on, she was in the ultimate no win situation but when puch came to shove, she came through for us, just like always"
MM - "shes a pariah to her people, we're all she has left"
SM - "believe me j'onn, i feel for her, but after everything thats happened, i honestly dont know is i ever could completely trust her again"
GL - ...
BM - "we're arguing in circles, time to vote"

Comment: @velorum
S1e11 (JLU) Wake the dead, time index 21:20
Reporter - "do you have a comment on your dismissal from the justice league?"
*camera switches, to show SM and GL flanking HG*
GL "hawkgirl was never dismissed from the league. she can come back whenever she likes."
HG - *blink blink*
GL - " i recused myself because. . well anyway, superman broke the tie.
HG *smiles and turns to SM*
SM- " i believe in second chances. i believe in redemption but mostly . . .i believe in my friends."
i hope that satisfies you in no longer thinking it is headcannon.

Comment: @paul d waite
i never said it was impossible or even implied it. as he and flash were the only ones defending her, and wonder woman was clearly dedicated to kicking her, GL did not want to vote, and supes broke the tie, logic dictates, those were the votes.

Comment: @TylerH
it is a quote from Sherlock Holmes. it is relevant due to the simple fact of logic. having watched batman the animated series, superman the animated series, justice league and at the point of writing this reply, all but 2 episodes of JLU, watching and getting a feel for the characters and their evolution throughout all the shows, batman voted out, MM voted in. that is the logical process of elimination.

Comment: “never said it was impossible or even implied it” — except when you quoted Sherlock Holmes saying that once you’ve eliminated _the impossible_, what remains must be the truth. That seems to me like it implies that any alternatives to your answer are impossible.

Comment: @JamesBlack Thanks for the reply; however it sounds like it is actually completely _irrelevant_ to the question or answer (you don't even reference the quote in your actual answer)... instead just acting as some sort of post "signature" (which isn't allowed here). That aside, it also sounds from your comment that this is just your opinion based on watching a lot of animated DC shows, rather than referencing specific moments showing how Batman and Martian Manhunter _actually voted_ (which is what the OP is asking for here). So I have to give a -1 for being inaccurate/unsourced.